# Java - redraw background

Tags: java, graphics, awt

I want to redraw background with different image. Here's a SSCCE example - I'd like to add an action to Listener that will repaint with another image.

```
package painting;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;

public class SwingPaintDemo3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI(); 
        }
    });
}

private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    System.out.println("Created GUI on EDT? "+
    SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Swing Paint Demo");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    f.add(new MyPanel());
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
} 
}

class MyPanel extends JPanel {

private int squareX = 50;
private int squareY = 50;
private int squareW = 20;
private int squareH = 20;
Image img;

public MyPanel() {

    setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            moveSquare(e.getX(),e.getY());
        }
    });

    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            moveSquare(e.getX(),e.getY());
        }
    });

}

private void moveSquare(int x, int y) {
    int OFFSET = 1;
    if ((squareX!=x) || (squareY!=y)) {
        repaint(squareX,squareY,squareW+OFFSET,squareH+OFFSET);
        squareX=x;
        squareY=y;
        repaint(squareX,squareY,squareW+OFFSET,squareH+OFFSET);
    } 
}


public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(250,200);
}

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);      
try {
    img = ImageIO.read(new File("graphics/close_0.jpg"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null); 
    g.drawString("This is my custom Panel!",10,20);
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(squareX,squareY,squareW,squareH);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawRect(squareX,squareY,squareW,squareH);
}  
}
```

So what method should I call to redraw background with different image?

Comment: For better help sooner, post one [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (as opposed to 3 separate source files).

Comment: `Graphics g = screen.getGraphics();`  Ughh.  What code were you looking at that gave you that idea?  Throw it away.  See [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As much as I understand the question (which is 'very little') this source might lead you forward.  Note that code should **never** attempt a potentially blocking operation (like loading an image) within the `paint` or `paintComponent` method.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class SwingPaintDemo3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}

private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    System.out.println("Created GUI on EDT? "+
    SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Swing Paint Demo");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.add(new MyPanel());
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
}
}

class MyPanel extends JPanel {

private int squareX = 50;
private int squareY = 50;
private int squareW = 20;
private int squareH = 20;
Image img;
Random r = new Random();

public MyPanel() {
    img = new BufferedImage(40,40,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            img = new BufferedImage(
                r.nextInt(getWidth())+1,
                r.nextInt(getHeight())+1,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            moveSquare(e.getX(),e.getY());
        }
    });
}

private void moveSquare(int x, int y) {
    int OFFSET = 1;
    if ((squareX!=x) || (squareY!=y)) {
        squareX=x;
        squareY=y;
        repaint();
    }
}


public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(250,200);
}

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    g.drawString("This is my custom Panel!",10,20);
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(squareX,squareY,squareW,squareH);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawRect(squareX,squareY,squareW,squareH);
}
}
```

Comment: I'll try to explain. In method paintComponent(Graphics g) there's line:     g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null); which draws image as the background. In my example the image is file close_0.jpg. I'd like to draw new background with different image - lets say xyz.jpg after the mouse is pressed.

Comment: Ummm yes.  That is exactly what the altered source does.